# Correctly terminate spawned runghc process

Tags: unix, haskell, spawn

With a script like

```
-- foo.hs
import System.Process
import Control.Concurrent

main = do
   a <- runCommand "yes"
   threadDelay 1000000
   terminateProcess a
```

I get expected behavior -- `yes` runs until the `threadDelay` is up. But if I replace `"yes"` with `"runghc bar.hs"`, where bar.hs is

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent

main = forever (print 5 >> threadDelay 100000)
```

...then bar.hs runs forever. Is there a better way to get runghc to terminate?

*Edit:*
This behavior is on linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty funny behavior. What's going on is that `runghc` spawns its own child process, and you kill the `runghc` process but not the child. Using [`interruptProcessGroupOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process/docs/System-Process.html#v%3ainterruptProcessGroupOf) in place of `terminateProcess` seems to do the trick here, though I don't really know enough to say whether that's a reliable/correct solution.

Comment: This behaviour is rather surprising, IMHO. It could be regarded as a bug of the GHC runtime, especially because the child was not explicitly spawned by the Haskell programmer, but by the runtime, hence it looks hard to override.

Comment: @chi Well, I'm sure it's not the runtime, but rather `runghc` which is choosing to spawn a process. But I agree with your conclusion that it's a bit surprising that `runghc` chooses to do this. I suspect that this is just the easy way to implement it: I bet we're essentially seeing `ghci` sandboxing, even though there's no enclosing process that needs a sandbox.

Comment: I'm having mixed success with ```interruptProcessGroupOf```, but it's better than anything else I know of. Thanks